# SimpleAdapter including a button. Java, Android

Tags: android, simpleadapter

first time asking - hope you can help.

I've created a SimpleAdapter, and an ArrayList/HashMap which maps to a Layout containing an ImageView & 2 TextViews. When the SimpleAdapter is assigned to my ListView it all works exactly as expected. My problem is this -
I want to add an ImageButton to the Layout used by the SimpleAdapter and cant work out how to do this. I added the ImageButton to the Layout, and I think I have to create a corresponding ImageButton for each HashMap I add to the ArrayList, but its not doing what I thought. How do I hookup an OnClickListener & how do I reference this back to the ListView index of the item the button was clicked for ?

Hope this explanation makes sense, any code examples would be most helpful.
Thanks,
daveD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best option would be to use a [custom adapter](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Yes your right, thats working nicely. Thanks.